# Мерж удалённой ветки (вырезание из другой)

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Есть ветка `master`,`develop` от `master` и `useful_tools` от `master`. Ветка `useful_tools` мержится в `master` и удаляется. Как в текущий момент лучше всего смержить те изменения из `master`, которые были в `useful_tools`, в `develop`?

В `develop` нужны изменения только из `useful_tools`, а не все изменения из `master`, т.е. если бы `useful_tools` ещё существовал, то необходимо было бы смержить только эту ветку.

Что-то вроде `cherry-pick` для ветки?

Comment: так посмотрите через reflog хеш ветки и восстановите ветку useful_tools. а далее мержите как Вы умеете.

Comment: Вообще сомнительная затея.

Comment: команде `merge` нужен коммит (обычно один, но их может быть и ноль, и больше одного). как вы его укажете — напрямую в виде хэша, в виде имени указателя (ветка — это плавающий указатель на коммит), ещё [каким-либо понятным программе образом](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) — не играет роли. т.е., фактически, ваш вопрос сводится к тому, как узнать, на какой коммит указывал указатель до его удаления. такие вопросы даже здесь точно были, поищите.